# How to get weighted summaries of survey responses in R

Tags: r, survey, weighted-mean

I am analysing survey data. Since my demographic categories are discrete I can summarise responses within demographics using `prop.table`. However, I would also like to be able to summarise responses using survey weights. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [survey package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) is your friend.

See the functions `svyby`and `svymean` for some nice examples. Note that you have to specify the survey design via `svydesign`, which takes the weights as an argument, before applying the other functions.

Hope this helps!